# Upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 Wily and get QNativeImage: Unable to attach shared memory segment

Tags: qt, 15.10, spyder

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10.  I am still using the latest NVIDIA binary driver 352.41 from nvidia-352 w/ GT730 card.

When I start spyder and spyder3, the display is garbled with window elements wrongly sized and out of place.  I get the following error:

```
$ spyder
QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment. 
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0
```

.
.
.

Can someone help me resolve this error?

Thank you in advance!
-Bill

Here is a screen shot of the garbled spyder screen
[image: Here is a screen shot of the garbled spyder screen]

---

Update Nov 3, 2015:

The problem is occurring with multiple applications:  spyder, VirtualBox, and IPython Qt Console.   It seems like the BadDrawable error may be related to Qt with Ubuntu 15.10.

Here is a screen shot of the garbled IPython 3 Qt Console screen
[image: Here is a screen shot of the garbled IPython 3 Qt Console screen]

Comment: This works for other distribution such as Linux Mint : http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/244087/17362

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried the workaround described here?
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=200167

I had the similar problems with Skype, VLC and Double Commander on my laptop with Ubuntu 15.04 and the hack cured them all.

Just add the following line

```
QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native
```

to the file

```
/etc/environment
```

Comment: Hi John,  Thank you!  Setting  QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native sems to work for Spyder.   I will try it on the other programs I am having problems with and test it before I mark this as the answer.

Comment: Was having same problem with mumble and this fixed it.  But with fresh 15.10 install and intel drivers.

Comment: This answer works for me. I was having issues with skype, Krusader and smplayer. All of them seem to work fine now.

Comment: Although the graphics display looks better inside the programs, I think there is still something going on with 15.10.   In MeshLab, I am getting similar shared memory errors: `(meshlab:5121): Gdk-WARNING **: shmget failed: error 28 (No space left on device)`

Comment: Maybe there is realдy little space on your drive?)
Bill, if it woks, it would be fine to make description more general. I haven't seen a similar question related to Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 1):

```
QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native
```

works for me for VirtualBox.

Comment: Thanks again.  QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native seems to have fixed all the problems with programs I am using so far (it has only been a week since upgrade):  MeshLab, IPython, Spyder, etc.