# Qt based apps are broken after time

Tags: qt

I'm using Kubuntu 15.10 with Plasma 5 about 2 weeks.

It has been a few updates, but the problem is still, and it prevent to work normaly.

I don't know what problem is it, but this happens only with Qt apps.

[image]

[image]

So if i run open dialog from Firefox (which used GTK window?) or open Transmission app, they work normaly.

I tried check and uncheck of 'Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs'. Disable animation (ALT+SHIFT+F12). Select OpenGL render 3.1, 2.0, and so on.

I also tried diffirent version of drivers, currently i have Nvidia 352.41 (nvidia-352-update).

So there is my spec, maybe it's help a little bit.

- Kubuntu 15.10 (64-bit)
- KDE Plasma: 5.4.2
- Qt: 5.4.2
- Kernel: 4.2.0-18-generic
- Processor: 4 x Intel Core i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz
- Memory: 8GB
- Video: Nvidia GeForce GTX970

I really enjoy using plasma5 and KDE ecosystem, but this bug is very annoying.

**Upd 17.11.15**

This problem is also represented on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

[image]

Qt:5.2.1 on this ubuntu PC. So problem is more global then just KDE and Plasma.

P.s. sorry for my english.

Comment: I switch render engine on OpenGL 3.1 and restart(!) all software, and this looks like solution. I'll work tomorrow, and write here this as solution.

Comment: Bad news, problem is still here. :( Switch to OpenGL doesn't help.

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/693136/upgraded-to-ubuntu-15-10-wily-and-get-qnativeimage-unable-to-attach-shared-memo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes, native render for Qt is solution of this problem. Steps i'm doing to fixing:

1. `sudo nano /etc/environment`
2. Add new line to the bottom of the file (second line for me) with this `QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native`
3. Save and exit by pressing: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
4. Reboot the system: `sudo shutdown -r`

Thats it.